# NativeScript camera and saving various pictures

Tags: nativescript

I am trying to take various photos and as I take them I want them to appear in my view. 
The idea is to add photo objects to the model which is an Observable and with a Repeater in the view have them displayed.

Note that instead of the image object I am adding a simple strings to **noteImages** just to debug it.

What I have is:

The view model:

```
function NoteViewModel(info) {
    info = info || {};
    var viewModel = new Observable({
        id: info.id || null,
        title: info.title || "title default",
        description: info.description || "description default"
        noteImages: [{src: "xxxx"}, {src: "yyyyyy"}]
    });
    return viewModel;

}
```

The "controller":

```
...

var noteViewModel = new NoteViewModel();
exports.loaded = function(args) {
    console.log("Loading note view...")
    page = args.object;
    page.bindingContext = noteViewModel;
};
...
exports.takePhoto = function(){

cameraModule.takePicture({width: 300, height: 300, keepAspectRatio: true}).then(function(imageSource) {
    var image = new imageModule.Image();
    image.imageSource = imageSource;
    noteViewModel.mainImage = imageSource;
    // noteViewModel.noteImages.push( {"src": "test"} );
    noteViewModel.noteImages.set([{src: "test"}]);
}
```

And the view:

```
<Page loaded="loaded">
  <Page.actionBar>
    <ActionBar title="New note"></ActionBar>
  </Page.actionBar>
  <StackLayout>
    <Repeater items="{{ noteImages }}">
      <Repeater.itemTemplate>
        <Label text="{{ src }}" />
        <!-- <Image src="{{ src }}" /> -->
      </Repeater.itemTemplate>
    </Repeater>
  </StackLayout>
</Page>
```

NOTE: I know that I should be adding imageSource to the array of images, but for testing purposes I just want to see another item added to noteImages and shown by repeater...

Initial noteImages get displayed by the repeater so I guess bindingContext is working as expected. The problem is that when camera returns its imageSource and I do **noteViewModel.noteImages.set([{src: "test"}]);** the view is empty. Repeater is failing to pick up the new array...

Should Observable propagate changes on the property noteImages to the UI automatically or noteImages should be an ObservableArray itself?

What am I missing here? :) 
Thanks

**EDIT**: making progress...

It seems that if an Observable contains properties that are arrays these properties must be of a type **ObservableArray** So, my model is now:

noteImages: new ObservableArray({src: "image1"}, {src: "image2"})

insead of

```
noteImages: [{src: "image1"}, {src: "image2"}]
```

After taking the picture I do:

```
noteViewModel.noteImages.push( {"src":"aaaaaa"} )
```

And my view shows the "aaaa"

Comment: Just FYI - Depending how many images you end up with in the Repeater, it would be wise to use the ListView component for better performance. If you end up with some decent size pictures on Android you will end up crashing the app. Another FYI - That's a big thing for Android apps and why image caching is a big must have on Android (see Picasso and Fresco native libs)

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out

Comment: You can also use virtual-array with loadSizeto further improve performance - nice example for using image-cache with virual-array to load into ListView you can find here https://github.com/telerik/nativescript-sample-cuteness